# How to set up login pin system

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

i want to set up basic login page in xamarin.forms. There is no username/password, just a simple pin

**so far i have 3 pages to do this**

1. Sign-up Pin page
2. Sign-up Confirm Pin Page (re-enter pin to confirm)
3. Sign-in Pin Page
4. Main app page

**my project flow as follows:**

- 1st time user, will be prompt to "Sign-up Pin Page", than "Sign-up Confirm Pin Page", than "Main app page"
- user that already have created a PIN, will be prompt to "Sign-in Pin Page", than "Main App Page.

**issue is that** "Sign-up Pin Page", "Sign-up Confirm Pin Page", and "Sign-in Pin Page" all have the same view, other than a label. 95% of the code is same. so if i make a small change like change color, than i will have to do in 3 different pages

**my question is**, is there better way to do this. should I use just one page to handle 3 pages? and do if/else to see which stage of flow user is in?

```
if(FlowStage == "signup"){
   //code here
}else if(FlowStage == "confirm")
{
//code here
}else if(Flowstage == "signin")
{
//code here
}
```

Comment: Sounds more like a design question than a code question Software engineering might be a better place. Even then I would think the code details is insufficient to give any recommendations.

Comment: ok sound good, thank you

Comment: do you know ny place i can post this question?

Comment: It's a mixture of a security and a software design problem. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://security.stackexchange.com/ . I'd read the guidelines for both and decide which makes more sense. Probably latter.

Comment: ok, it not letting me delete this question so ill leave it up

Comment: You can use styles to apply shared styling between pages.  And you can use a custom base page class that provides common elements.  "95% of the code is same" is not helpful if you haven't actually shown us any code.